# Which is correct, send or sent?

Tags: word-usage

> The box will be **send** on Friday.

Or

> The box will be **sent** on Friday.

---

> So he knows who **send** him this amazing gift!

Or

> So he knows who **sent** him this amazing gift!

Answer (score 3):

For the first example, the correct sentence is

> The box will be **sent** on Friday.

This is because this sentence is a [passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) sentence, so it requires the past participle of the verb. The past participle of "to send" is "sent."

For the second example, the correct sentence is

> So he knows who **sent** him this amazing gift!

This is because the phrase "who sent him this amazing gift" is a [clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause) which requires a [finite verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_verb). Specifically, it contains the simple past tense of "to send," which is "sent."

Answer (score 0):

Sent, in both cases . Also, "I will send the box on Friday " and "So he knows who would send him . . . "

Comment: Welcome to ELU (and ELL). It might be helpful to explain **why** these are correct.